# How would I create a Python program that reads a list of numbers, and counts how many of them are positive

Tags: python, list, loops

I need to create a Python program that will count how many positive numbers there are in a list of numbers. The list of numbers has to be typed in by someone. The end result must be the number of elements in the list that were > 0 
For an example, this is what you would see on the screen:

```
>>>Please enter a list of numbers separated by commas: 1,2,-3,-4,5,-6
>>>3
```

The answer would be 3 in this example. I am sorry if the question seems stupid, but I am a beginner and I am trying my best.

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` for Python 2.x (`input()` for Python 3) then `split()` the string at `,` and then count positive numebers, Example -

```
s = raw_input("Please enter a list of numbers separated by commas:")
print(len([i for i in s.strip().split(',') if int(i) >= 0]))
```

Comment: Why do we use raw_input?

Comment: Note that `raw_input()` only works on Python 2. On Python 3, use `input()` instead.

Comment: raw_input accepts input from user

Comment: Thank you very much I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. `input` returns tuple

```
>>> vals = input('get: ')
get: 1,2,-3,-4,5,-6
>>> len([item for item in vals if item > 0])
3
```

Python 3, `input` returns string

```
>>> vals = input('get: ')
get: 1,2,-3,-4,5,-6
>>> len([item for item in vals.split(',') if int(item) > 0])
3
```

By the way, zero is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: This way is better than Sharon's answer. But also only work on Python 2.

Comment: @KevinGuan Added Python3 solutuion